# how to refresh the ImageView after setting image from the server In my case its not updating the ImageView

Tags: php, android, mysql, image

The problem is that
when i get picture from the gallery and set it to Image View,
then it is set,but when i close that activity and open it again,
it is showing me the previous image not the updated one,
My code is sending image to the server perfectly and saving it to the Server,
also in MYSQL.
But when i try to retrieve the image from the particular URL it is not
retrieving the image.....

When I refresh the URL where the updated image is saved on the server,
it is showing me the updated image on the imageView like this.

Here is my downloadingimage class....

```js
package com.tut.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.InputStream;



public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    private ImageView imgView;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView imageView)
    {
        this.imgView = imageView;

    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(" Error coming data ", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
    {
        Log.e("result ", String.valueOf(result));
        this.imgView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
```

And here is my PHP Script to set the image and save update it to the database

```js
<?php

    // connect to mysql database
    $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","pass123");
    if (!$con){
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("TestDatabase", $con); // name of your database

    //check if "image" abd "CustomerID" is set

    if(isset($_POST["image"]) && isset($_POST["CustomerID"])) {
        $data = $_POST["image"];
        $CustomerID = $_POST["CustomerID"];
        $ImageName = $CustomerID.".jpg";
        $filePath = "images/".$ImageName; // path of the file to store
        echo "file ".$filePath;
        // check if file exits
        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            unlink($filePath); // delete the old file
        }
        // create a new empty file
        $myfile = fopen($filePath, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        // add data to that file
        file_put_contents($filePath, base64_decode($data));

        // update the Customer table with new image name.
        mysql_query("UPDATE Customers SET imageName='$ImageName' WHERE id='$CustomerID'")
            or die('Could not save Image Name: ' . mysql_error());

    } else {
        echo 'not set';
    }
    // close the connection
    mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For downloading images from the internet, use this library, it has ton of functions and works best:
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Mine problem is not downloading  the image, my problem is to set that image after i close that activity and when i reopen it will then show me the updated onel... I hope you understand now